# Fetch rows such that unique `date` values are equal to some value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to limit rows upto "unique date values" is equal to some value. that means I want to fetch data of 7 days.

For example, data is

```
1  1/2/2022  9:30  
2  1/2/2022  9:30  
3  2/2/2022  9:30  
4  3/2/2022  9:30  
5  4/2/2022  9:30
```

Here I want to fetch data upto 3 unique days

so expected output is

```
1  1/2/2022  9:30  
2  1/2/2022  9:30  
3  2/2/2022  9:30  
4  3/2/2022  9:30
```

Any ideas what could be possible query syntax for such conditional limit?

Comment: As per your output, the first and second row is same? Both are `non-distinct` , however, to answer your question , you can use `distinct` and `limit` clause in SQL , something like, `select distinct date from table limit 3` , check if it helps

Comment: You can use `dense_rank`

Comment: Could you confirm exactly what the data type of the column is please? Why not just use a where clause? e.g. if a datetime column: `WHERE DATE_COL IN ('2022-02-01 09:30', '2022-02-02 09:30','2022-02-03 09:30' )`  If it is a different data type then adjust the predicate to suit that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dense_rank`

```
select id,date_col
from (
  select *, dense_rank() over(order by date_col) r
  from (
    values
      (1, cast('2022-02-01 09:30' as datetime))
    , (2, '2022-02-01 09:30')
    , (3, '2022-02-02 09:30')
    , (4, '2022-02-03 09:30')
    , (5, '2022-02-04 09:30')
  ) d (id,date_col)
) t
where r <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A where clause is typically how rows are filtered e.g.:

```
select
*
from (
values
  (1, cast('2022-02-01 09:30' as datetime))
, (2, '2022-02-01 09:30')
, (3, '2022-02-02 09:30')
, (4, '2022-02-03 09:30')
, (5, '2022-02-04 09:30')
) d (id,date_col)
WHERE DATE_COL IN ('2022-02-01 09:30', '2022-02-02 09:30','2022-02-03 09:30' )
```

**rsult**

```
 id | date_col               
 -: | :----------------------
  1 | 2022-02-01 09:30:00.000
  2 | 2022-02-01 09:30:00.000
  3 | 2022-02-02 09:30:00.000
  4 | 2022-02-03 09:30:00.000
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02f1975a02cc090c34137b7f20bd9554)*

The syntax used in the predicate needs to suit the data type of the column in question.

To ensure your output will show the wanted range of dates/times even if they do not exist in the data, you first need to create those values and then outer join (typically a left outer join) your data to that. e.g.

```
;with CTE as (
    select
          id, date_col
    from (
    values
          (1, cast('2022-02-01 09:30' as datetime))
        , (2, '2022-02-01 09:30')
        , (3, '2022-02-02 09:30')
        , (4, '2022-02-03 09:30')
        , (5, '2022-02-04 09:30')
        ) AS d (id,date_col)
    )
select 
      CTE.ID
    , CTE.date_col
    , coalesce(t.some_col_here,'some value') as some_alias
from CTE
left join your_data as t on CTE.date_col = t.date_col
                   and t.other_col = 'something'

-- where (t.extra_col = 1 or t.extra_col IS NULL)
```

In this example you don't need the where clause for the date/time values (as these are now limited by the CTE contents that you provide), instead you may need to use the left join conditions to limit what data is included in the result. Note if you do use a where clause that you don't suppress rows that you need from the CTE.

Also note, you could use a "recursive CTE" to build a date/time range, there are many examples of doing that on this site or elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, but how do we know the data in IN () is always there in database? for example if 2 is not there we would only get upto 1, 2 date. while as i would want 4 in that case

Comment: **That detail isn't in your question!** (that you always want the values even if not present in the data). But the answer is that you must provide the value - just as I have in my answer above, then LEFT JOIN you data to that.